# Consistent Estimator beta distribution

Tags: statistics

Given $(X_i...X_n)$ i.i.d with the density:
$$
f_a = a \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot 1_{[0,1]}(x)
$$
and a>0. Also I know, that 
$$
-log(X_1)\sim \text{Exp}_a
$$
How do i show that 
$$
\hat{a}_n := -n \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n log(X_i)\right)^{-1}
$$
is a consistent estimator for a? I probably have to use the law of large numbers, but I can not figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-\log(X_i) \sim Exp(a)$ are i.i.d, you can apply LLN to deduce:
$$\frac{1}{\hat{a}_n}=-\frac{1}{n} \sum \log(X_i) \to \mathbb{E}[\log X_1]=\frac{1}{a}$$
Now it suffices to take the limit of the reciprocal to get $\hat{a}_n \to a$.

Comment: Should be $\cdots\to E(\ln X_1)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: oh, thanks, I didn't notice the typo.